# Using Cypher can I find a specific relationship between 2 distant nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 nodes not directly related to one another I know the start node, the end node and the relationship on the end node. For example

(u:USER)-[]->()-[]->()-[:WRITE]->(p:POST)

Is there a query I can write that would return 'p' to me? Also all the relationship in between are not WRITE, so I can't use [:WRITE*]

---

Secondary question: I'm thinking about permissions and relationships. In my model the User has a relationship on some entity and that entity to another all the way to a WRITE relationship on POST, and I want to therefore say the USER has WRITE on POST. But maybe I'm thinking about this wrong? Maybe I should just be giving USER WRITE on POST directly?

Thank you!

Comment: Please give us sample data and yoir expected result based on your sample data. Thanks.

Comment: You can use -[*]- if you don't know the relationship label, but is sounds like you better use apoc with something like apoc.path.expandConfig. This is the best I can offer without a sample data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the great advantages of Neo4j over relational databases is that you don't have to know the labels of nodes or how they are related to perform a useful query.

If you try

```
(u:User)-[*]->()-[:WRITE]->(p:Post) return p
```

it should give you what you want.

The structure of your graph will determine the efficiency of this query. If the graph between :USER and :POST is essentially a tree, then the above query should be quite efficient. However, if the intervening nodes and relationships form a network, then the query could spend significant time exploring all paths between :User and :Post in which case your idea of linking :User to :Post via a single relationship would be beneficial.

Comment: Perfect! That did the trick, thank you